# Загрузочный экран пока angular не загрузит всех данные

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как сделать загрузочный экран пока angular не загрузит всех данных ?

Создать скрипт который будет вешать картинку на все body и засунуть его в head.

Но как проверить что ангуляр загружен (то есть все модули, контроллеры выполнены) ? И уже на это событие снять тот блок с картинкой

Comment: `ng-cloak` скрывает элемент пока биндинг не отработал

Comment: Это я знаю, но я хочу сделать загрузочный экран, мол, подождите сайт загружается, и когда angular уже полностью выполнил все компоненты,  все проинициализировал снять его, чтобы не приходилось везьде писать ng-cloak или через ng-bind, чтобы не было пустого сайта

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294917/creating-a-splash-screen-using-ng-cloak

Answer (score 1):

**1 вариант.**
Можно сделать как подложку изображение в gif вынесенный за ng-view или ui-view.
Когда контент подгрузится он закроет эту картинку.

```
<div ui-view></div>
<div class="page-loading"></div>
```

**2 вариант.** Отследить событие на $rootScope.
 Для ng-view соответственно

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
  $('.page-loading').hide();
});
```

Для ui-view соответственно

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
  $('.page-loading').hide();
});
```

Если работа с Jquery соответственно в общей директиве ко всему сайту.

Comment: а если нет `ng-view` или `ui-view`? Ну и использовать jQuery напрямую в angular - не очень хорошо, для этого в ангуляре есть встроенные средства

Comment: @Grundy можно использовать JqLite, можно просто повесить ng-show на иконку загрузки, вариантов масса. Конечно лучше без jquery. Если нет ui-view и ng-view, можно использовать $timeout, который отработает после отображения всех директив

Comment: можете пояснить _Если работа с Jquery соответственно в общей директиве ко всему сайту._? вы его применяете не в директиве

Comment: @Grundy почему не в общей директиве? Если загрузочная иконка нужна на всех страницах

Comment: `$rootScope.$on` - Это директива?

Comment: @Grundy это не директива, а обработчик события, его можно заинжектить в директиву

Comment: Стоит пример привести